# Check if input is a number and if not input again

Tags: c++

I trying something really simple but in same time a little bit hard for me. I want to let user to insert number via console and if is not number to tell that is not and give chance to insert again while is number. 
Here is what I've made so far

```
int a;

 cout<<"enter a: ";
 cin>>a;
 while (!isdigit(a)); {
    cout << "\n ERROR, enter a number" ;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> a;
 }

system("Pause");
return 0;
```

Now I get error that is not number but the program is terminate. I can't insert again and must start it again.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018294/c-to-check-if-user-input-is-a-number-not-a-character-or-a-symbol?rq=1

Comment: A number is not a digit. It consists of digits, and sometimes more. You should look at duplicate questions.

Comment: Your life will be happier if you always initialize variables.

Comment: @luk32 a number's *representation* consists of digits. </pedantry> :P

Comment: Thank you @BrainlessBox .. this thread helped me to resolve my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` from the `while` line...

Then take care of the value you are testing for beeing a digit – `isdigit` expects a character, while you're providing the whole integer read from input (say, 57204, which is not a character code).