# C++ check input value with while loop

Tags: c++

I have the following problem. I try to check the format of the input value with the while loop. If the input is wrong, I want to get back and ask the user to give a new input. But this step is just skipped and it continues with the rest of the code. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance! P.S.: Credits is a double.

```
cout << "Enter amount of credits: "; 
cin >> credits;
while(cin.fail()){
    cout<<"Wrong input! Please enter your number again: ";
    cin>> credits;
}
```

Comment: `cin.fail()` doesn't verify the validity of the input. And to do that, we'd need first to establish what does "valid" mean.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail
refer this

Comment: I assume by validity of input, you want to check weather input has correct data type or not ?

Comment: Yes, I want to check if input is of correct data type.

Comment: @RulliSmith Please refer to my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C++ to check if user input is a number, not a character or a symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018294/c-to-check-if-user-input-is-a-number-not-a-character-or-a-symbol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the data type of input provided in a very simple way

```
cout << "Enter amount of credits: "; 
while(!(cin>> credits)){
    cout<<"Wrong input! Please enter your number again: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

`ignore` is necessary to clear the standard input, as mentioned in reference below *since `operator>>` won't extract any data from the stream anymore as it is in a wrong format*

For more reference you can check

1. [c++, how to verify is the data input is of the correct datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721911/c-how-to-verify-is-the-data-input-is-of-the-correct-datatype)
2. [how do I validate user input as a double in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273993/how-do-i-validate-user-input-as-a-double-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Your original code works with this modification:

```
while (std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cout << "Wrong input! Please enter your number again: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin >> credits;
}
```

As Tejendra mentioned, cin.clear and cin.ignore is the key.